# Variable is not modified in this loop - no-unmodified-loop-condition from ESLint

Tags: vue.js, while-loop, eslint

I have a project where ESLint throws this error from while loop. It does not make sence to me. Error says:

> 497:14  error  'from' is not modified in this loop  no-unmodified-loop-condition
>
> 497:22  error  'to' is not modified in this loop    no-unmodified-loop-condition

This is the code (look at while cycle):

```
mediaSettings: (state) => {
    const timestamps = [];
    const events = [];

    state.media.forEach( medium => {
        if( !medium.settings.dates ) return;

        medium.settings.dates.forEach( dateRange => {
            if( !dateRange.date_from || !dateRange.date_to ) return;

            const from = new Date( dateRange.date_from );
            const to = new Date( dateRange.date_to );

            while ( from <= to ) {
                if( timestamps.includes(from.getTime()) ) {
                    from.setDate( from.getDate() + 1 );
                    continue;
                }

                events.push({
                    date: new Date( from.getTime() ),  // Need Date clone via new Date().
                    mediumId: medium.id,
                });
                from.setDate( from.getDate() + 1 );
            };
        });
    });
    return events;
}
```

What is that? Can somebody tell me plase how to fix it? It does not make sence. This is not an error.

Comment: Maybe it's because from and to are constants?

Comment: No if I would use let instead of const ESLint will throw other error like use const instead of let....

Comment: I can't seem to replicate it... but it seems to just mean no changes were made during the loop. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unmodified-loop-condition#no-unmodified-loop-condition

Comment: Ok, ESLint might say use const instead of let, but I think you're trying to change a constant variable and that shouldn't work, and that's why the constant "'from' isn't changed in this loop". I couldn't test it at the moment, it's just in my head

Comment: No that is not the problem. The problem is this https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unmodified-loop-condition

Comment: Solution is below.

Comment: You are right, setDate() isn't re-assigning or re-declaring the constant and this should not be the problem. If you use /* eslint-disable no-unmodified-loop-condition */ it's just prevent the notification not fixing the error

Comment: But it is not an error. ESLint consider error also if you do not add space after the // comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found clever solution on [this page](https://learn.coderslang.com/0023-eslint-disable-for-specific-lines-files-and-folders/) which disables ESLint for some block of code and also a specific ESLint rules. It looks like:

```
    mediaSettings: (state) => {
        const timestamps = [];
        const events = [];

        state.media.forEach( medium => {
            if( !medium.settings.dates ) return;
            medium.settings.dates.forEach( dateRange => {
                if( !dateRange.date_from || !dateRange.date_to ) return;

                const from = new Date( dateRange.date_from );
                const to = new Date( dateRange.date_to );
                /* eslint-disable no-unmodified-loop-condition */
                while ( from <= to ) {
                    if( timestamps.includes(from.getTime()) ) {
                        from.setDate( from.getDate() + 1 );
                        continue;
                    }

                    events.push({
                        date: new Date( from.getTime() ),  // Need Date clone via new Date().
                        mediumId: medium.id,
                    });
                    from.setDate( from.getDate() + 1 );
                };
                /* eslint-enable no-unmodified-loop-condition */
            });
        });
        return events;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't get this error if you are using reassignable variables like this:

```
...
let from = new Date(dateRange.date_from)
let to = new Date(dateRange.date_to)

while (from <= to) {
  if (timestamps.includes(from.getTime())) {
    from = from.setDate(from.getDate() + 1)
    continue
  }

  events.push({
    date: new Date(from.getTime()), // Need Date clone via new Date().
    mediumId: medium.id,
  })
  from = from.setDate(from.getDate() + 1)
}
...
```